# php code in div id="upload" of xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true); not executing

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

In my .js file there is this line

```
xhr.open("POST", $id("upload").action, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
xhr.send(file);
```

in index.php there is a form like this

```
<form id="upload" action="upload1.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

So if I understand this ajax .open correctly, it should post the file sent to the action in the form id "upload" which is "upload1.php". Now if I go into upload1.php and have

```
file_put_contents('uploads/' . $fn,file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

it puts the file in a folder called uploads. But if i put something as simple as

```
echo "in upload1.php";
```

it completely skips over it and doesn't output anything. Ideally I want to redirect in upload1.php to redirect to another php file after it places the file in the uploads folder. But even header(""); etc. doesn't work.

Any help or suggestions? I'm new to javascript and ajax, finding it confusing.

Comment: What JS library are you using

Comment: You can't do a redirect in an AJAX call and expect the calling page to change. AJAX is for background operations within a page. If you want that page to move, then your ajax response will have to be a signal to the original javascript to do a `window.location` type thing.

Comment: Try checking what happens (whether there is even a request) with Firebug or a similar tool.

Comment: Do you want to change the page the user has been looking at after the "file" has been uploaded? If this is the case, you would probably be better not using AJAX for this particular job. Please explain exactly what you wish to achieve (from a user experience point of view) and we can try and help you do it.

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt output anything(at least to the screen) because you have made an xhr request. It basically means that the echo statement is sent to the caller, in your case the js file. So you have to see the response in

```
var return = xhr.responseText; //return in plain text
```

Plus, you can use another php files functions and classes, with include_once or require_once method. If you really want to redirect to another page, you can also do it with js code like :

```
window.location = 'some place';
```